# Missing argument 1 for Database::__construct()

Tags: php, database

Im trying to extend a simple database class.

```
<?php

class Database {

public $db;

public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}

public function insert($table, $row, $value)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO ? (?) VALUES (?)');
    $query->bindValue(1, $table);
    $query->bindValue(2, $row);
    $query->bindValue(3, $value);
    $query->execute();
}

}

?>
```

And this is my main class that extends the previous class:

```
<?php

class AdminAccount extends Database {

public function setValues($table, $row, $value)
{
    $this->insert($table, $row, $value);
}
}

?>
```

And this is what the $db variable is...

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'mydb';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $hostname . ";dbname=" . $database, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then i include, instantiate etc..

```
<?php


require_once('includes/settings.php');
require_once('includes/connect.php');
require_once('lib/class.database.php');
require_once('lib/class.adminaccount.php');

$database     = new Database($db);
$adminaccount = new AdminAccount();

$adminaccount->setValues('tasklist', 'creator', 'Zet');

?>
```

For some reason I get this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Database::__construct(), called in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/admin/extend.php on line 14 and defined in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Admin/lib/class.database.php on line 7

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Admin/lib/class.database.php on line 9

Why is this? Everything works just fine when I connect to the database WITHOUT EXTENDING.

Comment: You can't bind tables and columns; period.

Answer (score 1):

I see what is going on now.

You are extending Database in AdminAccount which includes the Database constructor.  Therefore you need to include $db when you are instantiating AdminAccount too or you need to write a new __construct() in AdminAccount.

Just from looking at your code, I don't see the point of you extending Database.  You should just pass $database to AdminAccount or instantiate Database in AdminAccount, but if you really do need to extend Database then the solution would be:

```
$adminaccount = new AdminAccount($db);
```

Comment: Sorry, my code isn't very clear. I am passing args, variable $db is inside 'includes/connect.php'

Comment: But how come it works if I don't extend and just query the database in  that particular class.

Comment: @user3527939 I have updated my answer after I saw what was happening.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense and I wasn't putting it together in my own code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$db` in your last piece of code is undefined. It hasn't been set. Constructor of Database class expects a value.

Comment: This is basically what I wrote previously but that isn't the issue.  The issue is that the Database constructor is also the constructor for AdminAccount since AdminAccount is extending Database.  See my answer.